# Who owns a recorded Skype conversation?

Tags: internet, criminal-law, privacy, india, human-rights

If someone records my Skype conversation, is that video his property or mine?

Is there a law against him making that video public or even recording it to begin with?

Country- India.

Comment: You need to clarify your country and jurisdiction within that country of origin in order to answer.

Comment: @gracey209 _"jurisdiction within that country of origin"_ . What does this mean?

Comment: In US it means state, and if it's a federal matter that should be known. In UK, England/Wales, Ireland, or Scotland.

Comment: @gracey209 In Australia, state or territory etc.

Comment: This is also why when folks post a question knowing where they are is so important.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the answer to [What is considered "public" in the context of taking videos or audio recordings?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/what-is-considered-public-in-the-context-of-taking-videos-or-audio-recordings/1380#1380); if either of the participants is in Australia than unless all parties have given consent then the recording is illegal.

Notwithstanding its legality, property in the recording vests in the person who made it. There is no law against him keeping it. There is no law against him publishing it unless the material contained is offensive, hate speech or defamatory (see [Customer feedback gathering in Australia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/customer-feedback-gathering-in-australia/2200#2200)).

Comment: In the U.S.it depends on the jurisdiction. Skype is considered a conversation for most part ( the video component rarely making a difference- unless it's a child depicted or there's nudity). I'll provide U.S. and UK answer in morning ( in NYC time so it's 3 am.) This is what is so great about the Internet. Australia is literally as far around the world for me as one can get, and it is interesting to see the commonality in their laws on this site!